# Google Apps Script not uploading file: "NetworkError: Connection failure due to HTTP 500"

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a WebApp that consists of an upload form for files, which are then stored on Google Drive. The application is mainly used to transfer images and PDF files.

Recently a user has reported that the app is failing with a specific PDF file. This file is a PDF of 72MB. It has been created by combining 7-8 other PDF files together, into one file. The app works when each of those individual files are uploaded one by one, but is not working when submitting the combined PDF (72MB).

I tried this on the app myself with the file in question. The app throws an error when reaching the sentence:

```
google.script.run
```

An error popup appears saying: **"NetworkError: Connection failure due to HTTP 500"**. The error appears pretty fast, I just have to wait 1-2 seconds for it. So I'm discarding a timeout situation here.

On the server side script, I have several Logger.log() calls, but I don't get any of them (when hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after trying the upload). 
I only see the debug logs registered when loading the form iteself (the logs I added for the doGet()), but no logs at all for the upload() function, called after hitting the upload button on the page. It seems as the google.script.run sentence fails even before reaching the first line of the code on the server side. I confirmed this by commenting out all of the server side upload code, and leaving ONLY a Logger.log() call.

This is my app source code:

HTML Form:

```
<form id="form1" method="POST" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="inputFile" name="inputFile" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload File" onclick="upload(this);">
</form>

<script>
  function upload(fileUploadInput) {  
    if (validateUploadForm(fileUploadInput.form)) {  
      console.log("Launching upload..");
      google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(uploadFileSuccessHandler)
        .withFailureHandler(uploadFileFailureHandler)
        .uploadFile(fileUploadInput.form);
      return false;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Server Side Script:

```
function uploadFile(form) {
  Logger.log("Entering uploadFile()");
  /* 
  Commentted code starts here... but it doesn't even reach the previous line!
  Throws "NetworkError: Connection failure due to HTTP 500" on a popup 
  at the page before logging anything.
  */
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would not be surprised that a large file breaks functionality. What's the smallest file you can use that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I tried uploading incrementally bigger files. It start failing with files larger than 50MB. At least a 49 MB went ok, and a 56 MB failed... So it might well be 50 MB the limit, or around it. Thanks for the tip @tehhowch